# How to Initalize the weights of nn.ConvTranspose2d in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

How can I initialize the weights of `nn.ConvTranspose2d` by bilinear interpolation? I have found `nn.init` witch supports initialization of each layer by random numbers from a normal distribution or zero initialization but there was nothing about interpolation. Also, interpolation can be utilized for upsampling in `torch.nn.Upsample` but in this way, the layer is not trainable.
Any idea on how to initialize a trainable ConvTranspose2d layer with bilinear interpolation?

Comment: Why exactly would you initialize it with bilinear interpolation as opposed to just initializing it with random numbers?

Comment: It is written in the paper. I am implementing deep3d in PyTorch. I also saw that this option is available in Keras but could not find anything like that in PyTorch. I think it is suggested for better convergence and avoiding local minima.